# Anystock not working with Anychart-NodeJS

Tags: node.js, jsdom, anychart

I'm setting up a node.js server that renders static jpg/png images using Anychart.

It is possible for me to return the simple example pie charts in the examples but when I try to return the examples for AnyStock, I get some weird results.

The code should create and return a stock chart on the url: `xx.xxx.xxx.xx:3000/insert`.
Instead the code returns this chart without any graphs or candlesticks:
[image: The result from node.js]

When I set the same graph up on a plain html site, I get following result:
[image: The result on web page]

The node.js code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var router = express.Router();


app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    var query = require('url').parse(req.url, true).query;

    var stock_id = query.stock_id;
    var type = query.type;

    if (type == "insert") {

        var JSDOM = require('jsdom').JSDOM;
        var jsdom = new JSDOM('<head><script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.9.0/js/anychart-core.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.9.0/js/anychart-stock.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script></head><body><div id="container" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div></body>', {
            runScripts: 'dangerously'
        });

        var window = jsdom.window;
        var anychart = require('anychart')(window);
        var anychartExport = require('anychart-nodejs')(anychart);


        var table, mapping, chart;

        table = anychart.data.table();
        table.addData([
            ['2015-12-24', 511.53, 514.98, 505.79, 506.40],
            ['2015-12-25', 512.53, 514.88, 505.69, 507.34],
            ['2015-12-26', 511.83, 514.98, 505.59, 506.23],
            ['2015-12-27', 511.22, 515.30, 505.49, 506.47],
            ['2015-12-28', 510.35, 515.72, 505.23, 505.80],
            ['2015-12-29', 510.53, 515.86, 505.38, 508.25],
            ['2015-12-30', 511.43, 515.98, 505.66, 507.45],
            ['2015-12-31', 511.50, 515.33, 505.99, 507.98],
            ['2016-01-01', 511.32, 514.29, 505.99, 506.37],
            ['2016-01-02', 511.70, 514.87, 506.18, 506.75],
            ['2016-01-03', 512.30, 514.78, 505.87, 508.67],
            ['2016-01-04', 512.50, 514.77, 505.83, 508.35],
            ['2016-01-05', 511.53, 516.18, 505.91, 509.42],
            ['2016-01-06', 511.13, 516.01, 506.00, 509.26],
            ['2016-01-07', 510.93, 516.07, 506.00, 510.99],
            ['2016-01-08', 510.88, 515.93, 505.22, 509.95],
            ['2016-01-09', 509.12, 515.97, 505.15, 510.12],
            ['2016-01-10', 508.53, 516.13, 505.66, 510.42],
            ['2016-01-11', 508.90, 516.24, 505.73, 510.40]
        ]);

        mapping = table.mapAs();
        mapping.addField('open', 1, 'first');
        mapping.addField('high', 2, 'max');
        mapping.addField('low', 3, 'min');
        mapping.addField('close', 4, 'last');
        mapping.addField('value', 4, 'last');

        chart = anychart.stock();
        chart.plot(0).ohlc(mapping).name('ACME Corp.');
        chart.title('AnyStock Basic Sample');
        chart.container('container');
        chart.draw();

        anychartExport.exportTo(chart, 'jpg').then(function(image) {
            fs.writeFile('anychart.jpg', image, function(fsWriteError) {
                if (fsWriteError) {
                    console.log(fsWriteError);
                } else {
                    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/anychart.jpg'));

                }
            });
        }, function(generationError) {
            console.log(generationError);

        });
    } else if (type == "image") {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/anychart.jpg'));
    }
});

app.listen(3000);
```

I suspect there's something wrong with the way I includes the JS-files in the jsdom. If I exclude the two files in the jsdom, I get the same result..

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a few days of waiting time, the AnyChart Support returned to me with the following answer for my question above:

> we can't guarantee that this module will work as expected. It depends
> on many other libraries that can't provide stable versions in
> different OS.

Instead they recommend to use their [Export Server](https://docs.anychart.com/Common_Settings/Server-Side_Rendering#web_server_mode) solution which is different from what I was looking for.

Our setup is built on a LAMP-server, so we don't want to run another server just for a few images a day.

If any of you have a suggestion for a solution where I can export my AnyStock charts to JPG, PNG or GIFs please let me know.

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check and share the browser console messages? That tends to be the first troubleshooting step :)

Comment: There is just one error message about the missing favicon. No error messages about any JS.